# How to make a visible field required

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a checkbox which when ticked shows a date box below. How can I set this date_to_destroy field to required if visible?

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If Me.Tick_if_destroyable = -1 Then
Me.Date_to_Destroy.Visible = True
 Else
Me.Date_to_Destroy.Visible = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub Tick_if_destroyable_AfterUpdate()
If Me.Tick_if_destroyable = -1 Then
Me.Date_to_Destroy.Visible = True
Else
Me.Date_to_Destroy.Visible = False
Me.Date_to_Destroy.Value = Null
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks

Stuart

Comment: A complete answer requires knowing whether or not the [Tick_if_destroyable] field is part of the stored data or only a form control.  If only a form field, the checkbox may be redundant, since a null (i.e. blank) date value can indicate the same thing. If the checkbox is unchecked, should any date value be deleted (i.e. nullified) and not just made invisible, otherwise the stored data will appear to have had the checkbox checked.

Comment: If [Tick_if_destroyable] is stored with the date value, then a table-level validation rule (or even Data Macro) could enforce the required logic.  But once again, this seems redundant for the same reason that a null value of the date could be sufficient. In summary, a quick answer may seem sufficient although the overall design may not be complete to handle all situations.

Comment: A web search for "access field required based on another field" returns a number of solutions that may be helpful in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

In the form's before update event, add the below code.

```
IF Me.Date_to_Destroy.Visible And IsNull(Me.Date_to_Destroy) Then
MsgBox "Date to Destroy is required."
Cancel = True
End If
```

Comment: @Stuart  If the answer is Excellent, then please up vote it and mark it as the answer.  A comment is not sufficient on Stack Overflow to indicate the value of the answer.